# Preloading video content in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, html5-video, preloading

I'm building an EmberJS app that is effectively a slideshow and the slides are either images or videos.

I've found that, as each slide is loaded, there is a short delay whilst the image or video was loaded from the server.

In order to stop this delay, I've added a function to my application controller that extracts a list of the image urls from my models and then calls `images.forEach(i => { (new Image()).src = i });` on them. This has resulted in the slide rendering almost instantly, as the images are now loaded from the cache.

I was wondering whether there is something similar that I can do with the list of video URLs? The only info I've been able to find about preloading involves adding a `preload` attribute to the video tag but this won't work as the page HTML doesn't get rendered until the slide loads...

Comment: Is the delay due to Ember retrieving a model from the back-end?

Comment: No, the models are loaded into the store when the app initiates and from then on it's only using peekRecord so no more network requests...

Comment: I suspect that having a hidden component (it has `display: none`) that's inserted at the top-level (within the `application.hbs` template) which inserts `<video>` tags with the `preload` attribute set to `auto` will accomplish what you are thinking. However, depending on the browser implementation, it may prevent such preloading (as it knows that the video is not displayed).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to brute-force preloading an entire video (which it seems like you do in this particular case), I would recommend downloading the entire video using AJAX and then constructing a `<video>` element from the downloaded blob (assuming you are only supporting IE 10+). The process looks something like this:

1. Download each video using AJAX, this will give you a blob which represents the video file.
2. Create a string from the blob suitable for as a source for the `<video>` element. You can use the [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method to accomplish this.
3. Create the `<video>` element and set the `src` to the aforementioned string created from [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).